# How do packages/CLI tools like Poetry run with a single command in the terminal?

Tags: python, terminal, command-line, package

I've installed [Python Poetry](https://python-poetry.org/) on Windows via `pip` and noticed that I can simply enter `poetry` into any terminal and it will be recognized as a valid command (although not really do anything of course since I didn't provide any arguments). I didn't need to `cd` to a directory and then do something like `python poetry.py` to execute it. It seems to just magically work. There isn't even anything poetry related that I can see in PATH in my environment variables, so logic says a terminal shouldn't recognize `poetry` as a command.

How do these packages accomplish allowing users to simply enter the name of the package into a CLI to get them to work?

How do I create my own package that can do this (and distribute it via PyPI to work out of the box on any computer)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is that it is actually using the PATH variable.
The PATH variable is a long string that contains the path to multiple files and/or folders.

When you enter a command in a terminal emulator (Like Powershell or CMD), Windows looks at this Path variable, and tries to see if the command you entered matches any executable or shortcut at any location specified on the PATH, so while your PATH may not have changed it is possible that a poetry executable was added somewhere that your path already pointed to.

Another option may be that something was added to `C:\Windows` which wile it does not show up in the environment variable editor, seems to behave as if it were on the PATH.

Comment: Just checked PATH and `C:\Windows`. No signs of any poetry folders or anything related. I'm guessing it's doing it a different way.

Comment: @bitclip You could try running a `where poetry` in cmd to find out what exactly is being run when you type `poetry` (note that the command for power shell is different)

Comment: I got back `... AppData\Roaming\Python\Scripts\poetry.exe`.
So it looks like you were right after all. There is an env var that points to that `Scripts` directory and somehow Poetry is bandwagon'ing off it.